# How do I keep the same opacity level to a vector shape using pen tool

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, layers, cs6

I have been using the pen tool for more than 8 years already, but when I started using CS6, I have lots of difficulties using the pen tool.

I use the pen tool for vector portraits and I need to use opacity 10 for every vector. But when I add another shape on top of it, it gets back to 100% opacity, so I have to change it to opacity 10 again. This has caused me to spend a lot of time on something else than trying to make my work quick and fast. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Make a group, give it low opacity and continue by creating your shape layers inside that group.

I'd use the same method in older PS versions as well.

---

Here's a picture where all the shape layers have 100% opacity and they are inside a group with 38% opacity that affects all the layers in it.

[image]

Comment: it didnt work :( i mean i tried to group it, but when i add more layers to the group, it just widens the shape and doesnt add to the opacity

Comment: @vjlauron I'm not sure what's wrong, maybe I misunderstood something... Anyhow, I added image to my answer, maybe that makes it clearer ( I made this image in cs3, but it makes no difference. ).

Comment: oh thank you but that's not i want to accomplish :(

Answer (score 0):

Click the menu button on the top left of the Appearance palette, then uncheck the option "New art has basic appearance" and boom! Problem solved! :D. This works on Illustrator CC, and I guess it is the same on CS6.

Hope this helps!